# Pivot table could not overwrite existing merged cells

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmjrA.jpg)
[image]

I have problem with Excel, my Pivot table could not overlap because it would overwrite merged cells.

I tried make new pivot table, but it didn’t work, however it works in other PC.

Anyone help me please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Adding a bit more information on how your sheet is laid out, such as a screenshot, and some info on how you've tried to solve the problem will help the community to provide you with better answers.

Comment: That said, it sounds like your Pivot table is attempting to overwrite existing data on the sheet which contains some merged cells. Try moving your Pivot table to a new sheet or to the bottom of the worksheet to ensure that it has the space it needs.

Comment: Previously, a pivot table always overwrote the underlying data whether it was merged or not, but now it doesn't allow it to do so. It shows the following message. I tried it on another computer and it still worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please Using 'Find merged cells' function in Excel, from [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/find-merged-cells-d02b2a5a-a08d-4641-8d4d-b3f233daca2c), then remove merged cells.
Then refresh the Pivot table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).